# Convert UNC path to 'file:///' URL in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, path

I need to convert UNC paths to `file:///` URLs. For example:

```
\\fileserver\share\dir\some file.ext --> file://///fileserver/share/dir/some%20file.ext
```

Is there a built-in function for this?

Comment: That doesn't look like the right output. `file://///fileserver/share/file.txt` means a file on localhost whose name is `//fileserver/share/file.txt`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use the Uri class in the System namespace:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\fileserver\share\dir\some file.ext");
string url = uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: This gives "file://fileserver/share/dir/some%20file.ext" and not "file://///fileserver/share/dir/some%20file.ext" which op explicitly requested. What the "correct" way of encoding UNC paths as urls is can be a lenghty discussion, see e.g. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66194 - but nevertheless this fails at answering op's question.